# IntelliJ Idea: is there an equivalent of Visual Studio *.sln files?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am looking to add to my source version control a file from an .idea project which has relative paths to another projects. But I don't want to commit any file that is not required for this or with contextual info from my workspace.

In visual studio you have `*.sln` and `*.csproj` files, and you can use relative paths to `*.csproj` files to reference project dependencies.

Here, the analog thing to `*.csproj` whould be `pom.xml` files. When I import modules to the project, I can see a file is populated inside `PROJECT_DIR/.idea/modules.xml`, which contains references to some `*.iml` files. But those `*.iml` files are not path of the repository, they are local as `.suo` would be on Visual Studio.

If I remove all the files inside `.idea` folder except the `modules.xml` and try to import the project again, it is not working at all.

What I want to achieve is commit a file that others could use to import project with its dependencies in a single step, without dirty the repository with unneeded/invalid files.

Comment: Add your .iml file and .idea directory to your .gitignore (if you're using git)

Comment: If you have a pom.xml (or build.gradle), you generally don't need to commit IntelliJ specific files (unless you also want to share IDE specific options)

Comment: Unless you have your reasons, Java projects should be IDE-agnostic: you should not commit _any_ IDE files at all. Just the Maven pom file.

Comment: I know, my .idea folder is already included in git ignore, but I just wanted to add an exception for this/these file(s) (if exists) and include it/them. I am looking for some kind of "sln" equivalent and include it/them in the repository so other team members could open the project with Idea (we are all using the same IDE) and get all the dependent projects added as modules automatically into de project